# Why I can use non const variable to receive const function

Tags: c++

The outcome of this piece of program I am testing doesn't make sense to me:

```
class CC {
public:
    int a;
    CC();
    CC(int a);
    ~CC();
};

CC::CC() {
    this->a = 0;
}

CC::CC(int a) {
    this->a = a;
}

CC::~CC() {

}

const CC f() {
    CC cc(2);
    cout << &cc << endl;
    return cc;
}

int main() {
    CC cc = f();
    cc.a = 3;
    cout << &cc << " " << cc.a << endl;
}


result: // note the address are the same
0x7ffdd24b26e0
0x7ffdd24b26e0 3
```

What I don't understand is why I can use a non const variable inside main() to receive a const return value function? The memory address are the same so the two local variables should be pointing to the same object.

g++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

Comment: _"Why I can actually return the stack value?"_ - Because you're returning _by value_ which makes a copy of whatever you return. That's another important difference between Java and C++ - value semantics.

Comment: Ow my eyes.  The `CC` class name makes them burn when combined with lower case `cc` of the same with `cout`.  Make it stop :)

Comment: And please remove the irrelevant code (i.e. almost everything.)

Answer (score 7):

> why I can use a non const variable inside main() to receive a const return value function?

Because the return value of the function is *copied* into the variable `cc`. There's nothing wrong with making a non-`const` copy of a `const` object; it doesn't allow you to modify the `const` object.

Please repost anything else you want to know as a separate question.

Comment: If it is a copy why the variable address inside f() is the same as the variable address inside main()?

Comment: @darklord It's a compiler optimization.

Comment: @darklord The copy happens to be at the same address as the original. There is no problem here since the copy and the original don't exist at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you couldn't use a constant on the right side of an `=`, then `CC.a = 3;` would be illegal. That would be insane. It's certainly legal to use the value of a constant -- what else would you do with a constant?

As for returning a stack value, you're returning the *value*. The value is well-defined when the `return` executes. That the object ceases to exist later doesn't matter since you've already returned its value.

```
int foo()
{
    int i = 3;
    return i;
}
```

Here we return `i`'s value, that is, we return 3. Nothing wrong with that.

```
int& foo()
{
    int i = 3;
    return i;
}
```

Here we return a reference to `i`. But `i` no longer exists. That's not good.

Comment: In the last example `foo` returns `int&`, so `return i;` is correct. If we change it to return `int*` we need `return &i;`. Both are undefined behavior.

Comment: @darklord That would return a pointer to `i` by value. That would be perfectly fine since the value would continue to exist, however you couldn't dereference the pointer.

Comment: @Kevin It's not UB to return a pointer to an object that no longer exists. You can even compare that pointer to `NULL` or `nullptr` or cast it to a boolean. You just can't dereference it.

Comment: Right. I meant dereferencing the pointer as being UB. Still, no good code should return a pointer to a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, return value of `const CC` is the same as `CC`.

Given:

```
struct CC {};

const CC f() {
    return {};
}
```

the assembly code generated by g++ 4.9.3 is exactly the same as the assembly code generated for:

```
struct CC {};

CC f() {
    return {};
}
```

**PS**

This is probably specified somewhere in the standard that I can't find quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: [Why function in c++ can return stack values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213136/why-function-in-c-can-return-stack-values)

The reason that the two addresses are the same is because of RVO. So semantically the variable 'cc' inside main() is still a copy of the local variable inside f(). And since it is just a copy of the original object, it makes sense to assign the const return value to a non const variable.