# Why function in c++ can return stack values

Tags: c++

Consider the following program:

```
class C {
  ...
};

const C f() {
    C ret;
    cout << &ret << endl;
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    C value = f();
    cout << &value << endl;
}


result: // note the address are the same
0x7ffdd24b26e0
0x7ffdd24b26e0
```

The variable 'ret' in function f() and variable 'value' has the same memory address so it seems 'value' is not a copy of 'ret'. The variable 'ret' is a stack variable so it should be invalidated after f() returns. So why c++ allow returning a stack value inside a function?

g++ version:

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

Comment: There's no need to add a note about your second question being moved on either the first post or the second post. That's just extra noise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the address of ret and value being the same is the so called Return Value Optimization (RVO). It means that in this case a copy is not going to be performed. Note however, that you can not rely on this, as it is not bound to happen (although that will change with C++17 [at least the current draft]).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Comment: RVO explains it very well. Thanks.

Comment: Might be nitpicking, but this is actually a case of NRVO (**Named** Return Value Optimization).

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of copy-elision, specifically [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (return value optimization).  It allows you to avoid the performance penalty of returning an object.

I've worked with a lot of people who were unaware of RVO and wrote stuff like:

```
void get_stuff(std::vector<int>& foo /*and input params*/) {
    // add a whole lot of integers into foo.
}
```

because they thought this would be cheaper (by avoiding a copy) than:

```
void get_stuff(/*input params*/){
      std::vector foo;
      // populate foo.
      return foo;
}
```

This leads to unnecessarily verbose, and often difficult to read code.  It's quintessential premature optimization -- a mistake you won't be making, since you now know about RVO!

Comment: And knowing is half the battle. Yo JOE!

Answer (score 1):

Returning the function result by value is one of the places, where the compiler is allowed to elide a copy as an optimization and thus translates your code to the moral equivalent of this :

```
void f(uint8_t* memory) {
    new(memory) C; // create object reserved memory location
    cout << (size_t)memory << endl; 
}

int main() {
    alignas(alignof(C)) uint8_t value[sizeof(C)]; //<- reserve properly aligned raw storage of appropriate size on the stack
    f(value);
    cout << (size_t)&value[0] << endl;
}
```

This optimization technique is called NRVO (named return value optimization) and is actually a pretty natural consequence of most calling conventions which specify that - for values that can't be returned via a register - the returned value is put at an address that is specified by the caller anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is actually RVO. An equally valid hypothesis is that the storage of both `ret` and `value` is on the implementation's stack, and that they share the same stack slot because their lifetimes are effectively non-overlapping. There might have been an intermediary.